# how can I solve the limes of $n*log_2(n)$ vs $n^{log_3(4)}$

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I want to manually calculate which of these two functions ($n*log_2(n)$ vs. $n^{log_3(4)}$) has a higher asymptotic increasing without using a calculator or any software.

My approach till now was:

lim n-> inf: \frac {$n*log:2(n)$} {$n^{log_3(4)}$}

Now use L´Hospital and derive each function:
\frac {$log_2(n)$ + $1/ln(2)*n$ } {$log_3(4)* n^{log_3(4) -1}}

Now use L´Hospital again:
\frac {$1/(ln(2)*n)$ + $1/(ln(2)*n) $} {$1/ln(3)4 $ * $n^{log_3(4)-1}$ + $log_3(4)-1 * n^{log_3(4)-2} * log_3(4) $}

My problem: If I calculate like that it results to a wrong solution. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that correctly?

Comment: Take logarithms of both functions and compare `log n + log log n` to `k log n` where `k > 1`.

Comment: That said, I am voting to close the question because math only questions are off topic here. It could be a better fit for [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I also noticed that your first derivative was incorrect.

Your first derivative and second evaluation of L' Hopitals rule is incorrect.

You start with:
f(n)=n*log2(n)
g(n)=n^(log3(4))

This gives:
f'(n)=log2(n) + **n** * (1/ln(2)) * n^(-1)
=log2(n) + 1/ln(2)
g'(n)=log3(4) * n^(log3(4)-1)

This gives:
f''(n)=(1/ln(2)) * n^(-1)
g''(n)=log3(4) * (log3(4)-1) * n^(log3(4)-2)

With your error in the first derivate you would have gotten f''(n)=(1/ln(2)) * n^(-1) - (1/ln(2)) * n^(-2), which still allows you to factor out n and results in the same final result.

Now that you have n in all of it, you can factor that out:
f''(n)/g''(n) = 1/[ln(2) * log3(4) * (log3(4)-1) * n^(log3(4)-2+1)]
= 1/[ln(2) * log3(4) * (log3(4)-1)] * n^(1-log3(4))]

Which now can be represented as:
k * n^(1-log3(4)) where k>0.
And the limit as this approaches infinity is 0. That means n^log3(4) has a greater asymptote than n * log2(n).

Alternatively, you can simplify first.
Note that both have a factor of n which can be removed, so instead you can have:
f(n)=log2(n)
g(n)=n^(log3(4)-1)

f'(n)=(1/ln(2)) * n^(-1)
g'(n)=(log3(4)-1) * n^(log3(4)-2)

f'(n)/g'(n) = (1/ln(2)) * n^(-1-log3(4)+2)/(log3(4)-1)
=(1/ln(2)) * n^(1-log3(4))/(log3(4)-1)

Again, the limit is 0, meaning that n^(log3(4)) has a greater asymptote.

The only thing extra that is needed to know is that log3(4) is greater than 1 as 4 is greater than 3.
That means (log3(4)-1)>0 and (1-log3(4))<0.

Also remember that the correct result may not be what you think it is. These 2 equations cross when n~= 30 000

Also, I'm not sure if this belongs here or on math.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How do you relate f*(n) to  f'(n)=log2(n)+(1/ln(2))*n^(-1) ? 
I thought it as to be  f'(n)=log2(n)+(1/ln(2)) , because of the product rule, in second term the n should not be derived I thought.

To the topic: My question belongs to Algorithms Lecture of CS Department, I think that CS Math differs vom Mathematician Math. So I put that quesion here

Comment: Also I would like to know how you factored the n out (in the first version on that line: Now that you have n in all of it, you can factor that out:
((1/ln(2))n^(-1-log3(4)+2) - (1/ln(2))n^(-2-log3(4)+2))/(log3(4)(log3(4)-1))
=((1/ln(2))n^(1-log3(4)) - (1/ln(2))n^(-log3(4)))/(log3(4)(log3(4)-1)))

, I did not understand that completely

Comment: The product rule is used when you have a product, e.g. a(x)*b(x). In this case we had a simple addition a(x)+b(x). In this case the derivative is simply the sum of the derivatives. So you separately differentiate log2(n) and (1/ln(2))*n^(-1).

However I have now noticed there was a mistake earlier. f'(x) should have been log2(n)+1/ln(2).

For factoring, g''(n) was n^(log3(4)-2)*c, where c is a constant.
that means f''(n)/g''(n)=f''(n)*n^(-(log3(4)-2))/c.

And (a^b)*(a^c)=a^(b+c).

Then I just simplified the powers.